# Updating in Redux - Create a new state v/s update existing state

Tags: redux, state

The task is to create a reducer function to handle multiple authentication actions. Use a JavaScript switch statement in the reducer to respond to different action events. This is a standard pattern in writing Redux reducers. The switch statement should switch over action.type and return the appropriate authentication state.

There are two approaches that seem same to me. In fact, I feel method 2 is better than method 1 as it actually updates the state. However freecodecamp seems to believe otherwise. Can someone tell me what is the difference between the 2.

Method 1 - Create new objects

```
const defaultState = {
  authenticated: false
};

const authReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  // change code below this line
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return {
        authenticated: true
      };

    case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        authenticated: false
      };

    default:
      return defaultState;
  }
  // change code above this line
};

const store = Redux.createStore(authReducer);

const loginUser = () => {
  return {
    type: "LOGIN"
  };
};

const logoutUser = () => {
  return {
    type: "LOGOUT"
  };
};
```

Method 2 : Update existing object

```
const defaultState = {
  authenticated: false
};

const authReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  // Change code below this line
  switch(action){
    case 'loginUser':
    state.authenticated = true;
    return state;
    case 'logoutUser':
    state.authenticated = false;
    return state;
    default:
    return state;
  }

  
  // Change code above this line
};

const store = Redux.createStore(authReducer);

const loginUser = () => {
  return {
    type: 'LOGIN'
  }
};

const logoutUser = () => {
  return {
    type: 'LOGOUT'
  }
};
```

The error message that I get in Method 2 is as follows

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3mxa.png)

Comment: There is a good chance your components won't re render when you mutate state in the reducers. Not sure what the error is, maybe from a testing library that also didn't detect the change because you mutated state.

Comment: Thanks, but are states supposed to be immutable in Redux. it does not impose any restriction per se

Comment: Yes, in react and redux all state is [immutable](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#why-is-immutability-required-by-redux). After an action is dispatched and a new state is returned all `useSelector` or `mapStateToProps` methods are run, when they return a different object than last run react-redux will re render the component.